# Convert file path URL to string that can be passed to C API in Swift

Tags: swift, macos

I am reading the filepath of a file in Swift UI (URL Type) and I want to pass this as a char* to my C APIs. Following is the code that I have

```swift
struct Home: View{
    
    @State var fileName = ""
    @State var OpenFile = false
    var body: some View{
        
        VStack(spacing: 25){
            
            
            Text(fileName)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            
            Button(action: {OpenFile.toggle()}, label: {
                Text("Open")
            })
        }
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $OpenFile, allowedContentTypes: [.png]){ (res) in
            
            do{
                let fileUrl = try res.get()
                print(fileUrl)
                
                self.fileName = fileUrl.lastPathComponent
                
                let string_val = fileUrl.absoluteString
                
                shared_filename = string_val ////// GIVES AN ERROR
            }
            catch{
                print("error reading file")
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Variable "shared_filename" is of char* datatype. however, the line code that is marked as "GIVES AN ERROR" throws the following error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UnsafePointer' (aka 'UnsafePointer')

Any pointers?

I have tried to use withCString and UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating:) but I am new to Swift and I dont think I have used them correctly.

Comment: Please add the code what you are going to do with `shared_filename`. By the way you get the (file) path of an `URL` with `path` rather than with `absoluteString`.

Comment: As of now I havent written any code that will make use of shared_filename. I want to use this path to open the file in my C code using a simple fopen(), maybe. shared_filename is defined as following in a .h file that the swift code can access :  char* shared_filename;  .

Comment: In many cases a Swift `String` can be directly passed to a C function.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://gist.github.com/yossan/51019a1af9514831f50bb196b7180107

Comment: You need to be careful here. In C, the type system only expresses the types of values, but not the lifetime (whether you get back a ref to a shared object, or a unique-for-you copy, who's responsible for `free`ing it, etc.). That information is only conveyed through docs or convention (which the compiler can't help with), so you need to be really careful that any pointers you pass to C code live for long enough. E.g. when passing a Swift String to a C fn, that pointer is only valid for the duration of that fn call. If that fn decides to hold onto that pointer for later, it'll be dangling.